# How to remove a specific directory/file from all location in Ubuntu with a single command?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I need to remove a file and directory with name **wine** from all location with a single command. I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

If you have a solution please help me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Let's say you have **wine** in three different folder named folder1, folder2, folder3 then type this.                                                                       rm -r ~/Documents/wine/{folder1,folder2,folder3}

Comment: It is location specified, I need to do that search all wine folder from my computer and delete them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find . -type f -name **"*fileName*"** -delete

in your case

find . -type f -name **"*wine*"** -delete